# I have got an error while assigning value to int from an array

Tags: c#, .net

```
{
int num1 = backData[num4, num3 + num2, 0];

num1[0] += leftData[num4 + num, num3, 0];
}
```

I got an error that "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'".please help me.

Comment: what are you trying to do? `num1` is int, and you try to access it with indexing,

Comment: It's exactly as it says, you're trying to access an index of an int (`num1[]`), but ints do not have an index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `num1` in a single `int`, not an array.  Do you mean:

```
{
    int num1 = backData[num4, num3 + num2, 0];

    num1 += leftData[num4 + num, num3, 0];
}
```

However I suspect that that you are expecting `num1` to be a *reference* to the array location you calculate in the first line.  If that is the case just assign it directly:

```
backData[num4, num3 + num2, 0] += leftData[num4 + num, num3, 0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `num1` is an `int` then trying to use `num1[0]` makes no sense.  How about this:

```
num1 += leftData[num4 + num, num3, 0];
```